# How can I define first and last classes inside another class?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a block-border class and inside two block-content classes. I am using IE9 and up browsers.

Can someone help me define the following with Less.

```
.block-border { 

    &.admin > .block-content {

    }
}
```

I want to define xxx for only the first block-content class inside the block-border,
yyy for only the second block-content class inside the block-border and zzz for only the last block-content class inside the block border.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to define the first and last using less. I defined the base block-content but not sure about the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already used the correct syntax for `.admin` – the preceding ampersand `&`:

```
.block-border {

    &.admin > .block-content {
        &:first-child {
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
        }

        &:last-child {
        }
    }

}
```

This would result in CSS selectors like

```
.block-border.admin > .block-content:first-child {}
```

If you leave out the ampersand it would result in

```
.block-border.admin > .block-content :first-child {}
```

…which has a different meaning (select the first child inside `.block-content`).